# How to call vb6 functions in c#

Tags: c#, vb6-migration

How can I integrate some old VB6 functions/subroutines into a C# WebAPI project with least hassle?

Is it really a manual rewrite? Or can I keep the old code and just call the functions from my C# code somehow?

The code in question wasn't changed for the last six years and won't be changed for the next six years, but as everything goes web, it has to be reused in our Rest API.

Comment: You could use COM interop, but you really should rewrite it.

Comment: One option that might work is find a copy of VS2008 express and try converting the code to .net.  From there you should be able to create a library(.dll) that C# can reference.